# Symfony ExpressionLanguage evaluate string with dashes

Tags: php, symfony, expression, evaluate

I'm trying to evaluate some strings containing dashes with the symfony [ExpressionLanguage](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html) component.

Here is what I've got so far :

```
...
$string = 'user.chuck-norris.getId()';

$language = new ExpressionLanguage();
$evaluated = $language->evaluate($expression, $users);
...
```

This returns me the following error :

```
Variable "norris" is not valid around position 12. (Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\SyntaxError)
```

If I change the dash "-" by an underscore "_", this works, but I have slug system which use dash and I dont wont to change it if I can avoid it.

Is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: The dashes are interpretated as arithmetic operator (subtraction) http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html#arithmetic-operators I think that you unique solution is convert it to underscore.

Comment: Yes, just saw this. I have to add quotes (or double quotes) to the string to make it work like I wank. $string = '"user.chuck-norris.getId()"'; Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like stated by Yonel, dashes are interpretated as operator.

So for this to work, I just have to replace dashes by undescores

```
$string = 'user.chuck-norris.getId()';
```

And then before making the request, replace _ by -

```
$value = str_replace('_', '-', $value);
```